# Make execCommand("Copy") work on hidden input tags

Tags: javascript, php, input, hidden-field, execcommand

I'm currently working with a function hard coded in javascript in order to copy a tag's custom address combined with a pre-defined link. What I made is make an input type text element and set its value to what I want to copy but what happens turns out it didn't work the way I wanted to be. After pressing Ctrl +V, it pasted the second to the latest value in my device's clipboard. **How to make execCommand("Copy") to work on a hidden input tag? (The function is called upon an img tag's onclick attribute)**

```
function shareFile() {
        var hiddenItem = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenItem.type = "text";
        hiddenItem.setAttribute("style","display: none");
        hiddenItem.value = <?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"\"https://":"\"http://").$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/filesystem/openfile.php?dir=\" + " ?> encodeURI(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("r-directory"));
        hiddenItem.select();
        console.log(hiddenItem.value);
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        // location.href = "resources.php?smsg=The file's link has been successfully copied to your clipboard." <?php if (!empty($_GET['dir'])) echo " + \"&dir=".$_GET['dir']."\""?>;
        return false;

    }
```

P.S. As much a possible no jQuery please! Thank you.

Comment: You can't, the element which the `execCommand` copies content from, _must_ be visible at the time of copying. You can temporarily change the type and/or visibility just before copying, though. Users won't see this temporary change of visibility, since the page won't be rendered before all the script has been executed.

Comment: I've removing the setAttribute style display none, and added this.appendChild but still didn't work. Any workarounds possible for me to copy the string? I can send the value of the input to the console log even if it's hidden.

Comment: [Seems to work as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/bftfba6t/) ..? Notice, that the PHP code is executed only once, before the page even has been loaded to the client.

Comment: It works. It's just that the element is still not in the document. I forgot to add appendChild to any element I want it to be placed and hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **execCommand** works to those elements added to the any part of the **document** element.

the code lacks `document.querySelector("body").appendChild(hiddenItem);`

and can be hidden after executing the command -> `hiddenItem.setAttribute("style","display: none");`